# Hadoop ConnectException

Tags: exception, hadoop, connection

I recently installed hadoop on my local ubuntu. I have started data-node by invoking `bin/start-all.sh` script. However when I try to run the word count program

```
bin/hadoop jar hadoop-examples-1.2.1.jar wordcount /home/USER/Desktop/books /home/USER/Desktop/books-output
```

I always get a connect exception. The folder 'books' is on my deskop(local filesystem). Any suggestions on how to overcome this?

I have followed every steps in [this](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/) tutorial. I am not sure how to get rid of that error. All help will be appreciated.

Comment: Could you please paste the exception trace?

Answer (score 0):

copy your books file into your hdfs

and for the input path argument use hdfs path of your copied book file.

for more detail go through below link.

http://cs.smith.edu/dftwiki/index.php/Hadoop_Tutorial_1_--_Running_WordCount#Basic_Hadoop_Admin_Commands

Answer (score 0):

There is a bit of confusion here, when you run the `hadoop ...` command then the default filesystem which it uses is the **hadoop distributed filesystem** hence the files must be located on the hdfs for hadoop to access it.

To copy files from the local filesystem to the hadoop filesystem you have to use the following command

`hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal /path/in/local/file/system /destination/on/hdfs`

One more thing if you want to run the program from your **IDE** directly then sometimes you get this issue which can be solved by adding the

`core-site.xml and hdfs-site.xml` files in the conf variable something like

`conf.addResource(new Path("/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop/core-site.xml"));`
  `conf.addResource(new Path("/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop/hdfs-site.xml"));`

change the path above to the hdfs-site.xml and core-site.xml to your local path.

So the above arguments can also be provided from the command line by adding them to the classPath with `-cp` tag.